# Optimize/Replace 'find' command

Tags: ubuntu, find, optimization

I am looking to optimize this find command. We have to move a bunch (sometimes almost a million) files to a directory for further processing. We are looking for a way to increase the speed of this command as it can take hours to run with a large amount of files. The problem is we need the files to be at least 1 minute old before moving them as we don't want to move ones that could still be being written to.

```
find path -name *.cdr.xml -mmin +1 -exec mv {} /path
```

**Edit:** This command is being ran as a part of a python script and we MUST wait for all the files to be found and moved prior to continuing on with the python script.

All the file names are UUID's.

Answer (score 1):

One performance improvement could be achieved by using the `+` ending with the `-exec` action of `find` which will cause `-exec` to be forked only once.

While in case of `;`, the `-exec` will be forked each time for a new argument.

So you can use :

```
find path -type f -name '*.cdr.xml' -mmin +1 -exec mv -t /path {} +
```

If there is a chance of duplicate file names :

```
find path -type f -name '*.cdr.xml' -mmin +1 -exec mv -it /path {} +
```

Or

```
find path -type f -name '*.cdr.xml' -mmin +1 -exec mv --backup=numbered -t /path {} +
```

`--backup=numbered` of `mv` will result in a numbered backup of files instead of overwriting in case of same file names in the destination.

Comment: The file names are UUID's and the processing happens immediately after this command happens, we are just moving them as more come in constantly.

Comment: @electrometro That means very little change of duplicate names, check my edits..

Comment: The other concern is we need the find command to be a blocking command as this is being ran as a part of a python script that cannot continue until all the files are found and moved. Does the `+` at the end of exec stop the blocking?

Comment: Yes the `+` will block until all the files are moved, but you might get to another problem with this method because it concatenates all the results into a single command, and the shell has a limit. If you pass millions of files this way it surely will fail.

Comment: @Dalvenjia I second with you..there could be an issue with `MAX_ARG`

Comment: @Dalvenjia, heemayl: I don't think so.  I'm  pretty sure that `find … -exec … +` will do as many execs as it needs to stay within the relevant limits.  And, BTW, unless you do `-exec sh -c "…" +`, the shell has nothing to do with it — `find` executes the requested program (e.g., `mv`) directly.

Comment: @Scott I have rechecked it & you are right :)

Comment: Tested `find ... -exec .... +` and it seemed to crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Watchdog (https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/) to keep all your logic in python, you could watch the directory and move each file after a minute without modification.

The other solution is to use **rsync** to transfer all files from **find** output instead of constructing with **-exec**.

A little explanation:

`find ... -exec ... \;` -> This will execute the command for each result, this add a lot of overhead and is very slow.

`find ... -exec ... +` -> This will concatenate all the results and execute the command just once, this is very fast but you may reach the shell's character limit for a command (specially with millions of files).

Now with **rsync**:

`find path -name *.cdr.xml -mmin +1 -print0 | rsync --remove-source-files -0 --files-from=- ${DESTINATION}`

Explained:

`find ... -print0 |` -> This will pass all the results NULL separated to the pipe to be processed by the rsync on the other side.

`--remove-source-files` -> This is self explanatory, just like `mv`.

`--files-from=-` -> This will read stdin from the pipe

`-0` -> This will read NULL terminated list instead of lines from the pipe.

Why NULL?... To speed up a little bit, NULL takes less bytes than a new line, take this to a million and you save a bunch of bytes.

Comment: No, on Unix & Linux, a newline is one byte.  The reason to use `-print0` and `-0` is that filenames can contain newlines, so a line-by-line list of filenames is inherently ambiguous.  Filenames *cannot* contain NULLs, so a NULL-separated list of filenames is unambiguous, even in the presence of filenames containing newlines.

Comment: Waiting for another big batch to try this one out. Might be a few days before we have one.